# Keras training with early stopping: how does it work when data is distributed?

Tags: keras, gpu, tensorflow2.0, google-ai-platform

In Keras (TF 2.4.1) I'm training a model on Google AI Platform. The job runs on a cluster with 1 master and 1 worker. Each machine type is [complex_model_m_gpu](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/machine-types) that includes four NVIDIA Tesla K80 GPUs. My job is configured to stop early based on a metric that I calculate at each epoch (recall@k). When I look at the logs after training finishes I can see that my metric is calculated two times at each epoch and that subsequent tests to determine if metric has improved or not are made on "parallel tracks", each track not knowing the other. For example at epoch 1 I get two numbers: 0.13306 and 0.12903. Later at epoch 3, I get 0.17 and 0.11; 0.17 is compared to 0.13306 and 0.11 to 0.12903 (see image below, read from bottom to top)

[image]

Why two numbers? It's like if the master and the worker are calculating the metric each separately. Is there a way to get only the global measure and to determine the improvement only on this global number?

By the way when I look at my scalar graphs in Tensorboard, my graphs are jumbled. Is it because I get multiple numbers at each epoch on a machine with multiple devices?

EDIT: I tried the same on a single machine (1 master, no worker) and this time I see only one number and my tensorboard graphs are no more jumbled. I've just realized that a master and a worker configuration probably needs something different in my code (a tf.distribute.MultiWorkerMirroredStrategy instead of a MirroredStrategy). I have to investigate that. Ref: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/multi_worker_with_keras

Comment: im not sure but did you check if one metric for train and other for test/validation?

Comment: No the metric is only calculated on validation set